# convert Json date into PHP date formate?

Tags: php, json, datetime

How we convert2016-03-01T03:00:00Z this date format like

```
2016-03-01T03:00:00Z
```

into `01/02/2016 03:00 AM`

also maintaining the timezone information.

One method is to explode the string with "T" character but problem into the 'AM' and 'PM'  specification.

Comment: how to turn march 1 into February 1? no need to explode `T` even `strtotime` will be able to understand that format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `date` with `strtotime` :

```
<?php
$a = "2016-03-01T03:00:00Z";
echo date("d/m/Y H:i A",strtotime($a));

?>
```

Demo  : http://codepad.org/O73INg7p

Answer (score 0):

I think we must consider the timezone (`'maintaining the timezone information'`). If default timezone different from the time string's timezone, the result will not correct.Just like this case:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Shanghai'); 
$a = '2016-03-01T03:00:00Z';
echo date("d/m/Y H:i A",strtotime($a));
?>
```

the result is `01/03/2016 11:00 AM`

The time formate is [`ISO 8601`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601),it will contain the timezone.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$a = '2016-03-01T03:00:00Z';
$tmpTime = explode('T',$a);
$resutTime = implode('/',array_reverse(explode('-',$tmpTime[0]))).' '.substr($tmpTime[1],0,5).' '.(intval(substr($tmpTime[1],0,2)) < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
echo $resutTime;
?>
```